# there is an error while parsing the apk in oreo

Tags: android, apk, android-8.1-oreo, parsing-error

I am getting Error while installing the Build APK in oreo device. its working fine with other devices except for the oreo.
Please help me.

**ERROR**:

> **There was a Problem Parsing the Package**

here is my Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 27
        dataBinding.enabled = true;
        defaultConfig {

            applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxx"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                postprocessing {
                    removeUnusedCode false
                    removeUnusedResources false
                    obfuscate false
                    optimizeCode false
                    proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your error, just giving us this usually won't allow us to help you.

Comment: @TJWolschon i have updated my question, please check now

Comment: what is the error you get

Comment: @dev *There was a Problem Parsing the Package*

Comment: check your buildToolsVersion is it compatible with your device?

Comment: Does this happen when you run to a device through USB debugging?

Comment: @UdeshUK not, it's happening when I have created a build APK and shared with my friends. its creating problem only on oreo devices

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput well from my experience this happen because the debug apks are build specifically  for that version to redus build time. Why don't you sign it with release key.